# Matlab cart2pol function

Tags: matlab

Does the Matlab's cart2pol() function calculate the value of theta differently? Here's an example i worked out when converting to polar coordinates using cart2pol.

First, i implement it with cart2pol.

```
N = 8;
x = 1:N; y = x;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
[theta,rho] = cart2pol(X-floor(N/2),-(Y-floor(N/2)))
```

which gives

[image]

Now, if i use the equation which is:

[image]

**Note in Matlab, -1 and +1 is not required**

```
theta = atan2((N-2.*Y),(2.*X-N))
```

i get:

[image]

Why is it that the value 3.1416 is negative for the cart2pol function and positive based on the equation?

Comment: Does it matter? It's the same angle.

Comment: @beaker yes it is, but i was just curious as in why aren't both the same if they were derived based off the same principle. It really caught me off guard when i analysed it at first. Glad to know that the difference is really not that big of a significant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As beaker said, the angle is the same. But regarding your comment: You can always use `edit <functionname>` to see how the Matlab function is implemented. This usually works for `.m` files, but not for `P` and `MEX` files, since these are binary and therefore can't be edited directly. So

```
edit cart2pol
```

in this case and you'll see that all `cart2pol`does, is just `atan2(y,x)` to get theta. So this means that the different results are just due to the fact that you call the function using different inputs than the inputs you use in your "formula".

```
atan2(-(Y-floor(N/2)),X-floor(N/2))
```

gives exactly the same result as your call of `cart2pol`.